# Load data before createStore

Tags: react-redux, axios

I’ve created some React files where one initializes a Redux store. However, I really need to load some data from a json file before store is initialized.

I’ve tried to import a script loading the json structure then assigning it to the createStore initialState value. But createStore runs before the data is loaded and assigned.

Is there any simple way to say “dont do anything before my axios call is done”???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action types
actiontypes.js

```
export const LOAD_DATA_REQUEST='LOAD_DATA_REQUEST';
export const LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS='LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS';
export const LOAD_DATA_ERROR='LOAD_DATA_ERROR';
```

Actions

actions.js

```
import * as Actions from './actiontypes';

function load() {
    return { type: Actions.LOAD_DATA_REQUEST };
}

function success(res) {
    return { type: Actions.LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: res };
}

function error(ex) {
    return { type: Actions.LOAD_DATA_ERROR, payload: ex };
}
export function loadData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(load());
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            dispatch(success(res));
        }).catch((ex) => {
            dispatch(error(ex));
        });
    };
}
```

use this in reducers that requires

```
import * as Actions from './actiontypes';
const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.LOAD_DATA_REQUEST:
        {
            //maybe you load
            newState.loading = true;
            return newState;
        }
    case Actions.LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS:
        {
            const res = action.payload;
            //do what you need  for this reducer

            return newState;
        }
    case Actions.LOAD_DATA_ERROR:{
         /// maybe you will want to show some error message in some reducer? 
        return newState; 
    }
}
```

You just need the first screen of your application on componentWillMount() call the loadData() action

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks :) I guess this will work. But in your case the Redux store is up and running already. My problem is that other components tries to access store values. So would like to load json object before createStore runs. But I guess your example is the best suggestion i’ve seen.

Comment: You are welcome .  think everything  like that  store as box ..  there is no difference filling it before createStore . Make a component SplashScreen  and while on one of your recuder  use  a property like loading state render   a message Like 'Loading Application Please  Wait' if the  loading  state is false  then render the childrens ( your main component)  . i hope it is clear now ..

Comment: Thanks Saltuk! Hide (no render) until load success. Thank you for helping me out.