# Handling Loading and null case from API in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Trying to show a loader for a little bit and then show the results - confused as to how to show null results scenario If I tie loader with zero results?
Here is my action and reducer: - I am trying to show a loader on every fetch call before I get the data..
action:

```
export function fetchdata(keyWord) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    Request.get(endpoint).then((response) => {
      dispatch({
    type: FETCHING,
      });
      dispatch({
        type: API_FETCH,
        payload: response.data,
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
        type: API_FAILURE,
        payload: error,
      });
    });
  };
}
```

reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
};
export default function myReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCHING:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
        count: count += 1,
      };
    case API_FETCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
        count: state.count > 0 ? state.count -= 1 : 0,
      };
    case API_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count > 0 ? state.count -= 1 : 0,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Parent COmponent:

```
....

    fetchData(value) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true }); - setting true / passing to child
        this.props.fetchdata(value);
      }

return (
<Child isLoading={this.state.isLoading} data={this.props.data} />
```

Child:

```
render() {
    if (this.props.isLoading && !this.props.data) return (<Loader />);
    const data = this.props.data ? this.props.data : [];
    const results = data.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>    
          <div>{item.name}</div>
        </div>);
    });
    return (
      <div className={`data ${visible}`}>
        <div className="data__list">
          {data}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: have you got any reducers ?

Comment: yes I do have it - tried dispatching a fetch before actual dispatch with a bool isFetching: true - but i does not work, also not sure how to reset it -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a question   may it will help . 
[Same logic with here please look my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162471/3912295)

if you are  multiple times fetching . then dont use boolean use a counter .

on reducer LOAD_DATA_REQUEST increase  fecthing_count
at LOAD_DATA_ERROR or LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS   decrease fetching_count

if the fetching_count is 0 that means you are not fetching and ready to render

as you request  think that we are naming API ActionTypes ( check my old answer to understand what i mean with action types )   with  for user USER_API_REQUEST , USER_API_ERROR, USER_API_SUCCESS  for others use same pattern  *_API_REQUEST , *_API_ERROR, *_API_SUCCESS

your reducer :

```
if (action.type.endsWith('API_REQUEST'))
    {
        //maybe you load
        newState.fetching= newState.fetching++; // increased then it is fetching 
        return newState;
    }
if (action.type.endsWith('API_SUCCESS'))
    {
        const res = action.payload;
        newState.fetching= newState.fetching >0 ?  newState.fetching-- : 0 ;  // decreased  or setted as 0 .. if 0 then no fetching 

        return newState;
    }
if (action.type.endsWith('API_ERROR'))
{
      //u can show     error message 
        newState.fetching= newState.fetching >0 ?  newState.fetching-- : 0 ;  // decreased  or setted as 0 .. if 0 then no fetcing 
    return newState; 
}
```

and on your component access your reducer and  check the property fetching  .

if fetching property larger than 0 then you have fetching request ( loading)  else  you can render your project

error is on your redux function in your redux function

```
export function fetchdata(keyWord) {
  return function(dispatch) {
/// you have to do it before starting request 
      dispatch({
    type: FETCHING,
      });

  Request.get(endpoint).then((response) => {
       /// Request is Success because of this it is not rising
/*
      dispatch({
    type: FETCHING,
      });
*/
      dispatch({
        type: API_FETCH,
        payload: response.data,
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
        type: API_FAILURE,
        payload: error,
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Could you point me to an example? How to deal with this within the parent component and pass it on to childhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/3912295/saltuk

Comment: Updated my question with my reducer - how does this work again ..? I see it is always 0 - when I get the data before getting data- what am i missing here?

Comment: added action as well

Comment: updated .. be carefull next time while coding if you dont want to lose more time ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158740/discussion-between-saltuk-and-monkeyjs).